# Unselect the select box once isClearable is clicked or true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I wanted to unselect the Input box once the close button is selected after the option is selected

I have attached [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-css-styling-forked-px9uf6)

**Current output**
When user select the option value is displayed when close icon is clicked it removes the option but select box is selected unless you click outside, it un-selects the box

**expected output**
When user select the option value is displayed when close icon is clicked it removes the option and un-selects the box as well.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about something named 'focus'.

This is actually built-in browser behavior, so if you want it to lose focus in some cases you can do it programmatically using refs.

[Here is a link](https://reactgo.com/react-remove-focus-from-a-element/) to guide where you can find how to do it

Comment: can you please help me out in react-select, not sure how to do it with react-select

Comment: Try passing a ref into your react-select Select and do the rest stuff like in guide.
You will have something like `<Select ref={selectRef}  />`

Comment: I found a solution for you, some guys was wondering about same thing as you, `const onChange = (_, { action }) => action === "clear" && setTimeout(() => selectRef.current.select.blur(), 1);`

I took it from this link https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/1309